# How do I test a 220v tanning bed without an outlet?

Tags: electrical

I have been blessed with a tanning bed that runs on 220 plug, which I do not have in my home. Before I pay someone to put a 220 outlet into my home, I wanted to know if there is any way I can test the tanning bed first to see if it works first?

Comment: If at all possible, ask the person you got it from if you have any faith they would tell you if it has issues. If you moved it to your home already, (or didn't), you could always plug it in elsewhere to test it if that's an option at all. Check behind the clothes dryer, in a basement or utility rooms, and also look behind the stove or in a garage (are there any double ganged breakers in your breaker box)? Do you have spare slots on your breaker panel? Anyways, I'm not certain anyone can tell you how to test it short of plugging it in and trying it. There are bulbs, controls, etc to test

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with home improvement.

Comment: Basically what @noybman said. Your question implies you are not comfortable installing a 220V outlet yourself. Therefore, your only option is to find an outlet that uses the same plug as your tanning bed and give it a try. If you post a picture of the plug we could tell you if you are likely to find such an outlet in your home but your best bet is to just compare it to the dryer or range plug. Most other 220V appliances in your home will be hardwired and I wouldn't advise you to take them apart.

Comment: *Now you know why you were "blessed" by it.*  220V tanning beds are like Christmas fruitcake that keeps getting regifted.  Do you have an electric dryer socket and your dryer is gas?  Or wiring for an electric water heater and it's gas now?  This job will be a lot cheaper if you put the tanning bed there.

Comment: @DanielGriscom, this seems like it would be a major appliance, so it would be on topic

Answer (score 3):

One option, if you truly don't have any 220v outlets in your home, is to take it to a local RV park/campground.

Most campgrounds have multiple outlet types and are easily accessed by a truck so I think this could be a great way to test an electric appliance before moving it into your home. You'll need a site with a *50 amp* hookup. I'd try public campgrounds before private ones.

[image: typical campground electrical hookup]

Comment: I’ve never seen a tanning bed with a 50amp plug or for that matter a straight blade plug.  If it’s a factory cord it will be twist lock.

Comment: This is a neat idea but not going to work for the reason @Tyson outlined. The locking plug is a safety feature and I don't think you will find a UL-listed adapter to defeat it (e.g. L6-30P female to L6-30R male). The adapters all go the other way around.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not familiar with what plugs are typical on tanning beds. I just know that the 4-pin 50 amp connector has the split phase voltage needed for 220V appliances. If the tanning bed uses a locking 3 pin connector, a cord like this might work: https://www.amazon.com/Conntek-1450SS2-15-Temporary-Generator-Straight-Blade/dp/B0046C6G7O

Answer (score 0):

You can't fully test it without plugging it in.  If you have an electric stove or an electric dryer, you may be able to plug in to test it there.  Otherwise, the electrician may be able and willing to temporarily tie it in at the box so you can make sure it works.  You may find a generator with the same plug, too.

However you go about it, you need to have power to it to test it.